# Is there a way to return a list of checked boxes in treeView [C#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, treeview

Here is what I tried

```
namespace USCS
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        List<String> CheckedNodes = new List<String>();
        public Form5()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeTreeView();
        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect_1(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Node.Checked)
            {
                CheckedNodes.Add(e.Node.FullPath.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                CheckedNodes.Remove(e.Node.FullPath.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect_2(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Node.Checked)
            {
                CheckedNodes.Add(e.Node.FullPath.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                CheckedNodes.Remove(e.Node.FullPath.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Behavior desc_behav = new Behavior();
            
            setBehaviorData(desc_behav);
           // Form5.ActiveForm.Hide();
           // var myForm = new Form5();
         //   myForm.Show();
        }
        private void InitializeTreeView()
        {
            treeView1.BeginUpdate();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("Parent");
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Child 1");
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Child 2");
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("Grandchild");
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Great Grandchild");
            treeView1.EndUpdate();
            
        }


        private void setBehaviorData(Behavior desc_behav)
        {
            var message = CheckedNodes[0];
            MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());



        }
        private void Traverse(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            String f;

            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                f = node.Text;
                Traverse(node.Nodes);
            }
            

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the "filepath" of the selected user boxes in the treeView. I just keep getting error messages that "index out of range" which makes no sense because it's pulling at index 0, or when I try to call the list directly I just get a System.checkednodes[system] message.

Literally just want it to return a string of the name path.

Comment: You are probably getting an event during the construction of the tree.   So simply add an if statement for CheckedNodes.Count > 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> checkedNodes = new List<string>(CheckedNodes(treeView1));
    foreach(string path in checkedNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(path);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<String> CheckedNodes(TreeView tv)
{
    foreach (string path in CheckedNodes(tv.Nodes))
    {
        yield return path;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<String> CheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection tnCol)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in tnCol)
    {
        if (tn.Checked)
        {
            yield return tn.FullPath;
        }
        if (tn.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (String path in CheckedNodes(tn.Nodes))
            {
                yield return path;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get all the checked nodes in treeview? If so, you can try to use recursion and subscribe to `treeView_AfterCheck`.

Here is a simple demo you can refer to.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.CheckBoxes = true;
}

List<String> CheckedNodes = new List<String>();

private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    CheckedNodes = GetCheckedNodes(treeView1.Nodes);
    foreach (var i in CheckedNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

public List<string> GetCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    List<string> nodeList = new List<string>();
    if (nodes == null)
    {
        return nodeList;
    }

    foreach (TreeNode childNode in nodes)
    {
        if (childNode.Checked)
        {
            nodeList.Add(childNode.FullPath);
        }
        nodeList.AddRange(GetCheckedNodes(childNode.Nodes));
    }
    return nodeList;
}
```